How do I get the download progress when I download the latest application using the fetchUpdateAsync method in the expo-updates library?
I have recently been learning how to hot update react-native applications using the expo-updates library. But I don't know how to get the download progress while doing the update in order to have a better user experience. I checked the relevant official documents, but did not find the relevant information.
